# How to find the Missing Files in Xcode?

Tags: ios, xcode, file

My Project Name is `Energyly`.I am Having a Issue in XcodeFile. My `Energyly.XcodeProj` shows in a red color.. i downloaded a project which is sent from another Mac .If i Open the File Means,It Shows Like This[image: Project Open Screen]

If i click the ShowinFinder for Pods file it shows the CorrectLocation.[image: ShowinFinder Screen]

Then If i open the Folder Location through Finder and i click the `Energyly.XcodeProj` it shows the file.But Code Which is updated by senior is not there…[image: Energyly.xcodeproj File]

1.Why `Energyly.XcodeProj` file  shows in a Red Colour?

2.Why the Updated Code in a `Energyly.xcodeproj` is not shown?

3.How to run This Project?

Comment: you can compare both project's file in Build Phase -> Copy Bundle Resources